# What and where is the technology used to project Rimmer in Red Dwarf?

Tags: red-dwarf, hologram

We know that Rimmer is described as a "hard light" hologram, but is there an apparatus that physically projects his image, or is there something inside of him that causes the a hard light field so-to-speak.

Answer (score 15):

It's a "light bee" that generates Rimmer, essentially it floats "inside" him.

Here is it floating (source [Red Dwarf Props](http://www.reddwarfprops.com/props-series6.html)):

[image]

Here's Lister holding it (source [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_Rimmer#Death_and_afterlife)):

[image: Rimmer's Light Bee]

Originally it was soft light, but it was upgraded by Legion in the episode "[Legion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_%28Red_Dwarf%29)" (Series 6, Episode ")

Here is Legion holding it during the upgrade (source [Red Dwarf Props](http://www.reddwarfprops.com/props-series6.html)):

[image]

And a close up of the prop (source [Red Dwarf Props](http://www.reddwarfprops.com/props-series6.html)):

[image]

Comment: The bee's paint job is not holding up well.

Comment: By the way, it's smaller in the book (only a centimetre across or so).

Comment: And I think originally in the TV series, there was no light bee, he was projected by Red Dwarf. It was introduced to enable him to visit planets, when the budget finally allowed for it (season 3?).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite indeed, see *Thanks for the Memory* where he is confined to a Holo-Projection Cage while off-ship.